# Turning an InputStream into a SeekableByteChannel

Tags: java, openal

I am attempting to convert an `InputStream` to a `SeekableByteChannel` in order to stream in Open AL with LWJGL.

The current code is as follows thanks to the help of a demo online:

```
InputStream source = Thread.currentThread().
                         getContextClassLoader().
                         getResourceAsStream(resource);
ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(source);
```

But I'm not sure, if at all possible, how I can seek through the OGG file in order to stream without converting it to a `SeekableByteChannel`

I'd be glad to supply more code if needed and thanks for any help in advance

Comment: I would not expect this to be possible.

Comment: Would you happen to know of any other way to seek the OGG file from within Java? Currently I read the whole which is not a good thing for a such a large file.

Comment: Presumably you'll have to open it as a [`FileChannel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html), which means opening it as a file rather than a resource, or perhaps converting the resource to a path.

Comment: In general, it doesn't work. If you give the concrete case, there might be a possible solution.

Comment: Does apache seven zip support compression?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [apache commons compress](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/) library, you can construct a `SeekableInMemoryByteChannel` from byte array. And convert `InputStream` to byte array is very easy also.

```
InputStream inputStream; // input stream
SeekableInMemoryByteChannel channel = new SeekableInMemoryByteChannel
       (IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream));
```