# How to check if an InputStream 7Z archive file is password protected or not?

Tags: java, encryption, password-protection, 7zip

I have used commons-compress-1.21.jar

```
File f = new File("/home/user/Desktop/test.7z");     
SevenZFile sevenZFile = new SevenZFile(f);
SevenZArchiveEntry entry = sevenZFile.getNextEntry();
sevenZFile.read();
sevenZFile.close();
inMemoryByteChannel.close();
```

This is working code to identify given test.7z password protected or not. While reading it's throwing:

```
protectedjava.io.IOException: Cannot read encrypted files without a password
    at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.AES256SHA256Decoder$1.init(AES256SHA256Decoder.java:57)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.AES256SHA256Decoder$1.read(AES256SHA256Decoder.java:118)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.utils.ChecksumVerifyingInputStream.read(ChecksumVerifyingInputStream.java:85)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:169)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.SevenZFile.readEncodedHeader(SevenZFile.java:289)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.SevenZFile.readHeaders(SevenZFile.java:191)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.SevenZFile.<init>(SevenZFile.java:95)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.SevenZFile.<init>(SevenZFile.java:117)
    at com.helloworld.ZipFileTest.main(ZipFileTest.java:45)
```

From this exception we can identify this is password protected file. But I have only an InputStream of the 7Z file. I don't have the file nor file path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SevenZFile` can accept `SeekableByteChannel` as parameter.

Just create `SeekableInMemoryByteChannel` from your stream.

```
InputStream inputStream; // input stream
SeekableInMemoryByteChannel channel = new SeekableInMemoryByteChannel
       (IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream));
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53075018/3656904)

Comment: first i was getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.tukaani.xz.LZMAOutputStream  error once i added xz-1.9.jar  its throwing run time exception       java.lang.SecurityException: sealing violation: package org.tukaani.xz is sealed

Comment: Create new question. Explain what you doing, what libraries you have (with versions), and add full stack trace. Errors like this is difficult to diagnose without precise details.